# How can i define and use a Laravel Directive without clearing the cache?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-blade, directive

I created custom directive for my project.
i have a table , when i do 0 ( zero ) in this active column as manually , i want my directive to work without running php artisan view:clear.
if i don't run php artisan view:clear, the directive doesn't work.
And i don't send any parameter for my directive.

How can i do this directive without running php artisan view:clear

My code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers\Directives;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use App\Models\Page;

class PaymentBladeServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $page = Page::where('key','payment')->firstOrFail()->active;
        Blade::directive('payment',function() use($page){
            return "<?php if( $page ) { ?>";
        });

        Blade::directive('endpayment',function(){
            return '<?php } ?>';
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to put the `$page` variable in your rendered blade directive. Blade directives are only "compiled" once and then never again until the view changes, so your directive will only work once.

Comment: I wanted to make like laravel . for example auth endauth.
if i send parametre it will be work i know . But i wanted to make without sending parameter.

Comment: You can, but you will have to add the database fetching to your "rendered" blade code.

Comment: How ? can you show me an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Blade::if() directive to achieve this and as @Jerodev says, in order to get your code to work you'll need put the $page variable inside the directive definition. Additionally, using Blade::if() will also automatically create the end block for you to use too, see the below example:

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::if('payment', function() {
           return Page::where('key','payment')->firstOrFail()->active; 
        });
    }
```

If you want the `$page` variable to be dynamic each time you call @payment(), you can add an argument to the function definition and pass in the value you want whenever you need to use the directive. See [this blog post](https://laravel-news.com/bladeif) on Blade::if() directives, and the official [Blade documention](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-blade) (change the version of laravel to the one you're using.